# jquery load passing a parameter

Tags: php, jquery

Hello just want to ask what is the proper way to pass a parameter using jquery my parameter is from a html input , below is my code.

```
function ajax_post(){


            var param = document.getElementById('def').value;


            $('#chatlogs').load('main.php?id='+param);



    }
```

I'm able to load the main.php but cannot get to echo the param, here is my main.php code.

```
<?php echo $_GET['id'];?>
```

Adding more details.. im getting the parameters from a HTML select input then after getting the value, will then load the main.php into a div with a id of #chatlogs.

```
<select name="topic" id="def" class="form-control" style="width:450px;" onChange='ajax_post()'>
                        <option value="" selected>---</option>
                        <option value="Solder Short">Solder Short</option>
                        <option value="Insufficient Solder">Insufficient Solder</option>
                        <option value="Misaligned Component">Misaligned Component</option>
                        <option value="Missing Component">Missing Component</option>
                        <option value="Inverted Component">Inverted Component</option>
                        <option value="Pad Contamination">Pad Contamination</option>


                    </select>  


<div id="chatlogs">
Please select a defect category...
</div>
```

[image]

Comment: Not sure about jquery but usually you just add the parameter to end of link, in your case '..id='+param) . This is if param is the value for id.

Comment: Thanks for the response still no luck tried main.php?id='+ param but still no return, no console log also. but i tried to hardcode the parameter main.php?id=test and my main.php is returning the test.

Comment: Check value of param, and let me know what it is.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
function ajax_post(){

var param = document.getElementById('def').value;

$('#chatlogs').load('main.php?id='+param);

}
```

Comment: Still no luck , now im getting "Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression:  HTMLSelectElement]" from the console log.

Comment: Try this: $('#chatlogs').load('main.php?id='+param);

Comment: Still no luck, i found a temporary work around by using the function document.getElementById('def').selectedIndex; then will put a if statement on my main.php, thanks for the response.

Comment: You're welcome. try my latest answer, it works on me :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<select name="topic" id="def" class="form-control" style="width:450px;">
                        <option value="" selected>---</option>
                        <option value="Solder Short">Solder Short</option>
                        <option value="Insufficient Solder">Insufficient Solder</option>
                        <option value="Misaligned Component">Misaligned Component</option>
                        <option value="Missing Component">Missing Component</option>
                        <option value="Inverted Component">Inverted Component</option>
                        <option value="Pad Contamination">Pad Contamination</option>


                    </select>  


<div id="chatlogs">
Please select a defect category...
</div>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#def').on('change', function() {
        var param = document.getElementById('def').value;
        //alert(param);

        $('#chatlogs').load('main.php?id=', param);
    })
});
</script>
```

Comment: You should edit you answer, rather than posting a new one.

Comment: Noted. sorry i'm a beginner :(

Comment: Tried this code , when putting the param on alert it gets the value (e.g Solder Short), but it seems it cannot pass it on .load looks like getting the value from a select input is the problem when i tried to change var param = "test" the main.php returns it.

Comment: @kaoriyui try ..id='+String (param))

Comment: Tried it,  still no luck. console.log tells the correct output but its not passing the value to main.php